# How many cores the standard c/c++ library function use in my desktop?

Tags: c, c++11

I use qsort() to sort an array. qsort is from stdlib.h in standard C/C++ library. I would like to know how many core/thread this function use when running this qsort() function?

Comment: All standard C functions are single-threaded. Other than that, it's impossible to say, as the operating system can actually decide to move your thread between cores, so while it will only use one core *at a time*, during the lifetime of the thread it might have occupied multiple cores.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that alone would suffice for an answer.